# Sqlalchemy many-to-many

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I seem to have a hard time locating an issue I have with the following many-to-many relationship:

```
class UserTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(UnicodeText)
    courses = relationship("CourseTable", secondary="user_course")

class CourseTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "course"
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(UnicodeText)
    users = relationship("UserTable", secondary="user_course")
    
class UserCourseTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_course"
    user_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    course_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('course.id'), primary_key=True)
    user = relationship("UserTable", backref=backref("user_course"))
    course = relationship("CourseTable", backref=backref("user_course"))
```

When querying for User

```
user = await self.session.execute(
    select(UserTable)
    .where(UserTable.id == user_id)
)
```

I get the following error:

```
When initializing mapper mapped class UserCourseTable->user_course, expression 'CourseTable' failed to locate a name ('CourseTable'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'app.models.db.user_course.UserCourseTable'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

I tried everything [described in their docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many), but to no avail: the error still persists

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

EDIT:
`SQLAlchemy==1.4.36`

Comment: You have defined `UserCourseTable` as a mapped class ("association object") instead of a plain table ("association table") so you would want to follow the [association object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) example. However, your `UserCourseTable` class does not contain any additional information - just the two FKs - so using an association table (as described at the link in your question) would be more straightforward.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks for you reply! Turned out, the problem appeared because I have the models in different files. Once I put them in a single file, everything works